# Entering cmd into the file explorer address bar not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, powershell, cmd.exe, address-bar

I was trying to open an instance of command prompt by typing 'cmd' on the windows explorer's address bar and pressing Enter but nothing happens.

Normally, an instance of the command prompt with the path where you opened it would appear. What might've stopped it from working?

[image: Command prompt command typed in the file explorer address bar]

--UPDATE--
Entering `powershell` into the address bar does not work as well.

--UPDATE 2--
Sample file path where I'm trying to access the command prompt: `C:\Projects\Python`

--UPDATE 3--
Entering `cmd` from `Windows + r` creates an instance of the command prompt.

--UPDATE 4--
After attempting to open powershell on the file directory, I got this error:
[Screenshot of Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtoYo.png)

--UPDATE 5--
I am using an administrator account. `Shift + Right Click` and pressing the
`Open powershell window here.` returns an error stating that the directory cannot be found.

--UPDATE 6--
I have made a factory reset on my laptop as the problem might be more severe than first perceived.

What is causing this error?

Comment: You are correct. That does not work. What is your question?

Comment: how does the folderpath look like? can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm talking about the file explorer here, not internet explorer @EBGreen

Comment: I repeat. What is your question.

Comment: @Dumblore He wants you to write "Why does this not work as it should?" at the end of your post

Comment: Post edited, sorry.

Comment: What version of windows? if you do `Windows` + `r` and type cmd does it work? I don't think powershell has ever launched from file explorer but I don't remember ever trying. `Windows-r` is faster so I do it that way if I want to use the keyboard.

Comment: @EBGreen Using the File Explorer's address bar will launch `cmd` in currently open folder, that's the key advantage of using it over Win+R

Comment: Do you have admin rights?

Comment: I have the same question.  Entering "bash" also does not work anymore. 
 I like being able to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux to launch "bash" in a folder

Answer (score 0):

Simply press `shift + right click` and you'll get an option saying :

> Open powershell windows here.

No need to press `win + r` because it is assigned to create an instance of cmd.

Answer (score -1):

For others having this issue.
It turned out the directory I was in was zipped.

Once extracted, typing cmd in the address bar worked as expected.